# Linux program act as a bluetooth slave device with a bluetooth adapter?

Tags: python, c, linux, bluetooth, bluez

I'm a new comer with bluetooth program, I want write some code to act as a bluetooth slave device and communicate with my iphone, I do not have a bluetooth development, I just have a bluetooth adapter plug into my lubuntu host pc, so is it possible to make some tricks with it, and communicate with my iphone just like a bluetooth handset?

Comment: we can use bluetooth pan and connect slave lubuntu to iphone over Bluetooth. Then all communications has to happen over TCP/IP tunneled over Bluetooth. Will that help ?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I prefer the possibility of this tech